# 3 weird images from a friend

Tags: logical-deduction, password, outer-space

I got sent this from a year ago, and I am still thinking what was the secret number that they hid a secret from, so here are the pictures.

The first one was a car, and a random equation.
[image]

The next one looks like a moon from Mars, with a random red circle. The person that messaged these from me said this has a connection with the first picture.

[image]

The last image has some text:
[image]

**What is the number, and what do these images mean?**

Comment: Are you *sure* that [[tag:logical-deduction]] applies here? That's only supposed to be used when formal logical reasoning (like grid puzzles, or liar puzzles) is required, not when you think that a small amount of informal logic is involved.

Answer (score 4):

> The equation in the first image can be broken out:
>  
>  µ = micro (International System of Units/SI prefix)
>  M = mega (International System of Units/SI prefix)
>  µM + S = ***MicroMegaS***

> The first image and second image work together as stated:
>  
>  The images are a speeding Chevy **Volt** (on a ***TEAR***?) and the crater **Voltaire** on the Mars moon Deimos. Voltaire is the author of the novella ***Micromégas*** which notably predicts Mars having 2 moons.

> **Immemorial** - originating in distant past; very old.
>  
>  Searching for immemorial in the text of ***Micromégas*** will yield this passage:
>  
>  *We have more matter than we need," said he, "the cause of much evil, if evil proceeds from matter; and we have too much mind, if evil proceeds from mind. For instance, at this very moment there are 100,000 fools of our species who wear hats, slaying 100,000 fellow creatures who wear turbans, or being massacred by them, and over almost all of Earth such practices have been going on from time immemorial.*
>  
>  Taking the 2 numbers from this passage (100,000) and multiplying them together will get you **10,000,000,000** or **10<sup>10</sup>** (the nth word?)

Comment: they didn't say you have to multiply.

Comment: Right, just trying to figure out a way to make "the nth word"